# How to find which entry has the most identical values in other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find province that has the most cities in them.

[image: Here is what my data base looks like.]

The best solution I came up with was joining the tables together and selecting only province and type of place (I need to find city). I did it like this.

```
select wojewodztwo,typmsc
from wojewodztwa inner join
     powiaty
     on wojewodztwa.klwoj = powiaty.klwoj inner join
     gminy
     on powiaty.klpow = gminy.klpow inner join
     miejscowosci
     on gminy.klgm = miejscowosci.klgm inner join
     typymsc
     on miejscowosci.kltm = typymsc.kltm
```

Where ''wojewodztwo'' is a column of provinces and ''typmsc'' is a column of types of places

[image: It looks like that]

Now I need to find a way how to select province (just one) that has the most cities inside of it.
I don't know how to look for the province that has the most occurrences of city("miasto") inside of the typymsc column

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It would also help if you translated the table and column names, so an English speaker could follow the question *and* the query.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I'll keep that in mind when asking about anything else.

Comment: What happens if multiple province have the same number of cities. It is understood that is highly unlikely, but keep in mind that as a developer your job is the *systematic control of miracles*.

Comment: Well I don't know to be honest. I am a student and this was one of my multiple tasks that i simply couldn't do :) (I'm supposed to learn from those tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to look for the province that has the most occurences of city("miasto") inside of the typymsc column

Use filtering, aggregation, `order by` and `limit`:

```
select wojewodztwo, count(*) as num_cities
from wojewodztwa inner join
     powiaty
     on wojewodztwa.klwoj = powiaty.klwoj inner join
     gminy
     on powiaty.klpow = gminy.klpow inner join
     miejscowosci
     on gminy.klgm = miejscowosci.klgm inner join
     typymsc
     on miejscowosci.kltm = typymsc.kltm 
where typmsc = 'miasto'
group by wojewodztwo
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```